# Trouble extracting body from SOAPMessage

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm trying to extract the body from a SOAPMessage and am getting some odd results. The sample code below should help illustrate my problem:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
message.writeTo(baos);
String messageString = baos.toString();
System.out.println("SOAP Message: " + messageString);

System.out.println("Body: " + message.getSOAPBody());
```

With the output:

```
SOAP Message: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://adc.appcomsci.com/schema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <sch:computeConfigurationResponse>
            <sch:file>
                <sch:url>http://goodSolution.com</sch:url>
                <sch:configurationFileType>Solution</sch:configurationFileType>
            </sch:file>
            <sch:file>
                <sch:url>http://error.com</sch:url>
                <sch:configurationFileType>Diagnosis</sch:configurationFileType>
            </sch:file>
        </sch:computeConfigurationResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
Body: [SOAP-ENV:Body: null]
```

Any idea why the body is null here? Is this not the correct way to extract the body for processing? If not, what should I do differently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

Printing out the body doesn't actually render the xml that exists within the body, just the actual body tag, which in this case had no attributes or text and so was null.